# Chain several operations in mathematica

Tags: mathematica

I have an implicit expression ((x-a)/a)^2+(y/b)^2=1. I want to find dy/dx. Mathematica should first solve `Solve[((x - a)/a)^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1, y, 
 MaxExtraConditions -> Automatic]` and on the result do `(d)/(dx)(y = (b sqrt(a^2-x^2))/a) = -(b x)/(a sqrt(a^2-x^2))`

How do I chain it in a single expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mathematica* has its [own SE-site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) such that you can ask it over there. Anyway, it's a short code but next time you must go to the above mentioned site:

```
Clear[a, b, x, y];
D[y /. Solve[((x - a)/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 == 1, y], x]
```

> Result:

```
{-((b Sqrt[2 a - x])/(2 a Sqrt[x])) + (b Sqrt[x])/(2 a Sqrt[2 a - x]),
  (b Sqrt[2 a - x])/(2 a Sqrt[x]) - (b Sqrt[x])/(2 a Sqrt[2 a - x])}
```